# CTE Types Don't Match error when using Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, common-table-expression, linked-server

I'm getting the following error: `Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "namePath" of recursive query "pathBuilderCte".`

My SQL looks like this:

```
 ;with pathBuilderCte as
 (

    select a.id
    , cast('root' as nvarchar(max)) namePath
    from [linkedServer\Instance].[dbName].dbo.table1 a
    inner join [linkedServer\Instance].[dbName].dbo.table2 b on b.aId = a.id 
    where a.column1 = 'Something'
    and b.id = 0

    union all

    select a.id
    , cast(p.namePath + '\\' + cast(a.NAME as nvarchar(max)) as nvarchar(max)) 
    from [linkedServer\Instance].[dbName].dbo.table1 a
    inner join [linkedServer\Instance].[dbName].dbo.table2 b on b.aId = a.id 
    inner join pathBuilderCte p on p.id = b.parentId
    where a.column1 = 'Something'
    and b.id > 0

 )
 select * from pathBuilderCte;
```

FYI: `Table1.Name` is of type `varchar(255)`

If I run this SQL on the linked server itself all works (with or without the casting in the second part of the CTE; but using only schema and table names).
However when I run this over a linked server (using the full linkedServer.DB.schema.table syntax) I get the above error.

Have I missed something obvious, or could this be a bug?

Comment: Try `N'root'` instead of `'root'`. Also in recursive part use `N'\\'`.

Comment: Thanks @HamletHakobyan; nice thought.  Sadly no luck (I tried putting casts around all strings to make them all nvarchar(max) and prefixing any hardcoded string values with Ns.

Comment: ps. I also tried using `nvarchar(4000)` in case `nvarchar(max)` wasn't allowed over a linked server.

Comment: what is the datatype of `id` of `table1` and the datatype of `parentid` of table2?

Comment: Also, try explicitely casting the datatype of `id` in your CTE: `SELECT CONVERT(a.id AS INT) AS id` and also in the `SELECT` after `UNION ALL`. (Obviously, use the correct data type)

Comment: @Lamak both are ints; and I've also tried putting cast to ints around them with no luck.  The error suggests it's the namepath with the issue; but good call on belt and braces approach.

Comment: Can you post the current code with the use `N'root'` and such?. Also please post the tables definition

Comment: What is the version of the linked server? Which provider does the linked server use? There could be some dumbing down of data types depending on these things...

Comment: Dump your anchor into a table. `(SELECT ... INTO dbo.t1 FROM..)` Observe the data types. Repeat with recursive query by removing the join to the recursive part (hard code for now). Compare your data types (lengths included)